# How to Combine 3 ID's when a button was clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I've try this code

```
<p>Watch Series Online</p>
<input type="search" id="imdbseries" class="Search" name="" value="" 
placeholder="IMDB ID">
<input type="search" id="season" class="Search" name="" value="" 
placeholder="SEASON">
<input type="search" id="episode" class="Search" name="" value="" 
placeholder="EPISODE">
<button id= "search" onclick="search()" >Watch Now</button>
```

```
<script>
function search() {
  var imdbseries = document.getElementById('imdbseriesID','season#',episode#').value
window.location.href = "https://mysiteurl.com/tv.php?imdb="+ imdbseriesID + "&season=" + season# + "&episode=" + episode#;
}
</script>
```

but fail for 3 ID's..

I want that when I fill the box with
IMDB ID:`tt9140554`
SEASON:`1`
EPISODE:`1`

it should go to this EXSACT URL when the button was clicked.
`https://mysiteurl.com/tv.php?imdb=tt9140554&season=1&episode=1`

Comment: You can not use `getElementById` like that, that takes _one_ ID, and returns _one_ element (if found.)

Comment: getElementById is used to get one element by it's ID and not multiple elements. Also, The # sign comes before the element's ID. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Comment: You need to read the values separately. You can't just pass more than one id to that function. Note that getElementById doesn't require the hash; the function name implies you need just the id. This is different for querySelector, which works like CSS and therefore does require the hash.

Comment: so how can a fix this

Comment: Did you have a working version for _one_ value? Well then use what you did there, two more times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html

```html
<p>Watch Series Online</p>
<input type="search" id="imdbseries" class="Search" name="" value="" 
placeholder="IMDB ID">
<input type="search" id="season" class="Search" name="" value="" 
placeholder="SEASON">
<input type="search" id="episode" class="Search" name="" value="" 
placeholder="EPISODE">
<button id= "search" onclick="search()" >Watch Now</button>
```

Your script

```js
function search() {
   // The document.getElementById() takes one Id
   let imdbseries = document.getElementById("imdbseries").value;
   let season = document.getElementById("season").value;
   let episode = document.getElementById("episode").value;

   location.href = `https://mysiteurl.com/tv.php?imdb=${imdbseries}&season=${season}&episode=${episode}`

}
```

Comment: Thanks, This works when I add the id's with #. But how can I make this thing open in a pop up window when the button was clicked

Comment: Actually you shouldn't add # in getElementById(). [MDN Referance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById#parameters)

Comment: Thank you. I got it :)

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the documentation for getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). As you can see it accepts only one argument.

An alternative is to use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). (You can tidy up the markup a little by replacing putting the id values in the name attribute, and removing the ids altogether.) Then you can just target elements by their name attributes, grab the values, and then [build a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

(Note: at some point you may want to add some validation to check the input values are valid. For example, both `season` and `episode` should both be numbers.)

```js
function search() {

  const imdbseries = document.querySelector('[name="imdbseries"]').value;
  const season = document.querySelector('[name="season"]').value;
  const episode = document.querySelector('[name="episode"]').value;

  console.log(`https://mysiteurl.com/tv.php?imdb=${imdbseries}&season=${season}&episode=${episode}`);

}
```

```html
<input type="search" name="imdbseries" placeholder="IMDB ID" />
<input type="search" name="season" placeholder="SEASON" />
<input type="search" name="episode" placeholder="EPISODE" />
<button onclick="search()" >Watch Now</button>
```